# Unexpected result when using converge to generate all rotations of a list

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I'm trying to get all the rotations of the list `v`. So, in the definition of `rotations`, I use the flipped version of `rotateLeft` as the first branching function (in order to accept the list first) and then a function that returns the list `[0, 1, 2, ..., v.length-1]`, with `map` as the converging function.

```
const {curry,mathMod,pipe,splitAt,reverse,unnest,converge,map,flip,length,times,identity} = require("ramda");

const v = [1,2,3,4];

const rotateLeft = curry((n,vet) => {
    const i = mathMod(n,vet.length);
    return pipe(
        splitAt(i),
        reverse,
        unnest
    )(vet);
});

const rotations = converge(map,[
    flip(rotateLeft),
    pipe(length,times(identity))
]);

rotations(v);
```

However, this doesn't return what I expected. Instead, it works fine if I rewrite that as follows:

```
map(flip(rotateLeft)(v),
    pipe(length,times(identity))(v));

// gives [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,1],[3,4,1,2],[4,1,2,3]]
```

As I understand, `converge` applies the two branching functions to `v` and then feeds the results as arguments to `map`. Is that right?
So why doesn't `rotations(v)` return the same thing?

[Code](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.23.0#?const%20rotateLeft%20%3D%20curry%28%28n%2Cvet%29%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20const%20i%20%3D%20mathMod%28n%2Cvet.length%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20pipe%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20splitAt%28i%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20reverse%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20unnest%0A%20%20%20%20%29%28vet%29%3B%0A%7D%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20rotations%20%3D%20converge%28map%2C%5B%0A%20%20%20%20flip%28rotateLeft%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20pipe%28length%2Ctimes%28identity%29%29%0A%5D%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20v%20%3D%20%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%5D%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20doesn%27t%20work%0Arotations%28v%29%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20correctly%20returns%20%5B%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%2C%204%5D%2C%20%5B2%2C%203%2C%204%2C%201%5D%2C%20%5B3%2C%204%2C%201%2C%202%5D%2C%20%5B4%2C%201%2C%202%2C%203%5D%5D%0Amap%28flip%28rotateLeft%29%28v%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20pipe%28length%2Ctimes%28identity%29%29%28v%29%29%3B%20)

**More concise version using `reduce`**

Inspired by your versions in *vanilla JS*, I've come up with the following `reduceRotations` function, which doesn't use the index parameter of `map` or recursion in an obvious way. Then, of course, I translated that into *vanilla Ramda*, in a totally point-free fashion. :)

```
const {converge,reduce,always,append,pipe,last,head,tail,identity,unapply} = require("ramda");

const reduceRotations = (v) => {
    const rotate = (v) => append(head(v),tail(v));
    return reduce(
        (acc,_) => append(rotate(last(acc)),acc),
        [v],
        tail(v)
    );
};

const pointFreeRotations = 
    converge(reduce,[
        always(converge(append,[
            pipe(last,converge(append,[head,tail])),
            identity
        ])),
        unapply(identity),
        tail
    ]);
```

[Code](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.23.0#?const%20reduceRotations%20%3D%20%28v%29%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20const%20rotate%20%3D%20%28v%29%20%3D%3E%20append%28head%28v%29%2Ctail%28v%29%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20reduce%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28acc%2C_%29%20%3D%3E%20append%28rotate%28last%28acc%29%29%2Cacc%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Bv%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20tail%28v%29%0A%20%20%20%20%29%0A%7D%0A%20%20%0Aconst%20pointFreeRotations%20%3D%20%0A%20%20%20%20converge%28reduce%2C%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20always%28converge%28append%2C%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20pipe%28last%2Cconverge%28append%2C%5Bhead%2Ctail%5D%29%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20identity%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%29%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20unapply%28identity%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20tail%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%29%0A%0ApointFreeRotations%28%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%5D%29)

**Yet another one**

The following equivalent functions employ `scan` instead of `reduce`.

```
const {converge,scan,always,append,head,tail,identity} = require("ramda");

const scanRotations = (v) => {
    const rotate = (v) => append(head(v),tail(v));
    return scan(rotate,v,tail(v));
};

const scanPointFreeRotations =
    converge(scan,[
        always(converge(append,[head,tail])),
        identity,
        tail
    ]);
```

[Code](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.23.0#?const%20scanRotations%20%3D%20%28v%29%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20const%20rotate%20%3D%20%28v%29%20%3D%3E%20append%28head%28v%29%2Ctail%28v%29%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20scan%28rotate%2Cv%2Ctail%28v%29%29%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aconst%20oneLinerRotations%20%3D%20%0A%20%20%20%20%28v%29%20%3D%3E%20scan%28converge%28append%2C%5Bhead%2Ctail%5D%29%2Cv%2Ctail%28v%29%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20scanPointFreeRotations%20%3D%0A%20%20%20%20converge%28scan%2C%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20always%28converge%28append%2C%5Bhead%2Ctail%5D%29%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20identity%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20tail%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%29%3B%0A%0AscanPointFreeRotations%28%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%5D%29)

Comment: Perhaps even cleaner than `const rotate = (v) => append(head(v), tail(v))` is the point-free version:  `const rotate = lift(append)(head, tail)`.  (The alternative `converge(append, [head, tail])` feels less elegant, and is definitely less standard.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `converge` takes as its arity the arity of the longest function supplied to it.

So, since `flip(rotateLeft).length //=> 2` and `pipe(length,times(identity)) //=> 1`, rotations will have length 2.  But you clearly want a unary function.  The easiest way to fix it is to simply wrap `flip(rotateLeft)` inside `unary`:

```js
const rotateLeft = curry((n,vet) => {
    const i = mathMod(n,vet.length);
    return pipe(
        splitAt(i),
        reverse,
        unnest
    )(vet);
});

const rotations = converge (map, [
  unary ( flip (rotateLeft) ),
  pipe ( length, times(identity) )
])

const v = [1,2,3,4];

console .log (
  rotations (v)
)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script><script>
const {curry, mathMod, pipe, splitAt, reverse, unnest, converge, map, unary, flip, length, times, identity} = R   </script>
```

Also note that this doesn't really require all of Ramda's machinery.  It's pretty easy to do this in vanilla JS:

```js
const rotations = v => v .map ( (_, i) => v .slice (i) .concat ( v .slice(0, i) ) )
```

Comment: Nice implementation using `map-slice`! I don't think I would've thought of that one :D

Comment: @user633183: Well, it takes advantage of `Array.prototype.map`'s (often unfortunate) extra index parameter.  It feels a bit like an abuse of `map`.

Comment: Oh, thank you! The arity... Well, it makes sense now!

Answer (score 3):

As proof by this simple recursive implementation of `rotations`, sometimes point-free code composed of tons of tiny functions just isn't worth the added headache -

```js
const rotations = ([ x, ...xs ], count = 0) =>
  count > xs.length
    ? []
    : [ [ x, ...xs ], ...rotations ([ ...xs, x ], count + 1) ]

console.log(rotations([1,2,3]))
// [ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 2, 3, 1 ], [ 3, 1, 2 ] ]

console.log(rotations([1,2,3,4]))
// [ [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], [ 2, 3, 4, 1 ], [ 3, 4, 1, 2 ], [ 4, 1, 2, 3 ] ]
```

Above, destructuring assignment creates many intermediate values, but we can work around this using a slightly different algorithm -

```js
const rotations = (xs = [], i = 0) =>
  i >= xs.length
    ? []
    : [ xs.slice(i).concat(xs.slice(0, i)) ].concat(rotations(xs, i + 1))

console.log(rotations([1,2,3]))
// [ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 2, 3, 1 ], [ 3, 1, 2 ] ]

console.log(rotations([1,2,3,4]))
// [ [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], [ 2, 3, 4, 1 ], [ 3, 4, 1, 2 ], [ 4, 1, 2, 3 ] ]
```

Defining a helper function like you did is good hygiene. It also makes our other function more readable -

```js
const rotate = (xs = []) =>
  xs.slice(1).concat(xs.slice(0, 1))

const rotations = (xs = [], i = 0) =>
  i >= xs.length
    ? []
    : [ xs ].concat(rotations(rotate(xs), i + 1))

console.log(rotations([1,2,3]))
// [ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 2, 3, 1 ], [ 3, 1, 2 ] ]

console.log(rotations([1,2,3,4]))
// [ [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], [ 2, 3, 4, 1 ], [ 3, 4, 1, 2 ], [ 4, 1, 2, 3 ] ]
```

Comment: Nice answer as always!.  I was about to write a recursive version of this when I thought up my `map` answer, and then didn't bother.

Comment: Well done! Nonetheless, my goal was to manipulate the previously defined ```rotateLeft```, with Ramda functions and point-free composition used as much as possible, mainly as an exercise. Otherwise, I would probably have written something very similar to what you did here... Check out my alternative version of ```rotations``` as well!